# PORTING FROM DB2 TO ORACLE - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I'm getting the error " ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" at  row: 7, column: 6
when I launch this query on ORACLE 11g DB:

```
 SELECT B.ID_COND AS IDCOND,B.ID_PAYMENT AS IDPAYMENT, B.DT_SCAD AS DATASCAD, B.DT_PAYMENT AS DATAPAYMENT,B.DE_CHANNELPAG AS CHANNELPAYMENT, B.DT_STARTVALID AS DATASTART, B.DT_ENDVALID AS DATAEND,
            B.IM_TOTAL AS TOTAL, B.ST_PAYMENT AS STATECOND, B.CO_CIP AS codCIP, B.ID_PEND AS IDPEND, B.TI_PAYMENT AS TIPOPAYMENT,
            B.cause_PAYMENT AS causaleCOND, B.IM_PAYMENT AS amountPAYMENT, B.DE_MIDDLEPAYMENT AS MIDDLEPAYMENT, B.DE_NOTEPAYMENT as notePAYMENT,    
            (select st_PAYMENT from QLT.paymnts P
                where P.ID_COND=B.ID_COND
      AND ROWNUM <= 1
                order by (CASE WHEN P.st_PAYMENT='ES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC, TS_INSMNT DESC
            ) AS STATEPAYMENT
    FROM  QLT.JLTCOPD B
        WHERE  B.ID_PEND = '269' AND B.TI_PAYMENT = 'S' 
        ORDER BY B.DT_SCAD ASC, DT_STARTVALID ASC
```

Trying to delete this row: 'order by (CASE WHEN P.st_PAYMENT='ES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC, TS_INSMNT DESC' no errors are shown and a result is returned.

I'm trying to convert a DB2 query to ORACLE, the original DB2 inner query was:

```
(select st_PAYMENT from QLT.paymnts P where P.ID_COND=B.ID_COND order by (CASE WHEN P.st_PAYMENT='ES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC, TS_INSMNT DESC fetch first 1 rows only)
```

How can I change it in order to do the porting without errors?

Comment: the "rownum" is applied before the "order by", so in your inner query the "order by" doesn't do anything

Comment: You're right! I'm trying to convert a DB2 query to ORACLE, the original  DB2 inner query was:

(select st_PAYMENT from QLT.paymnts P
     where P.ID_COND=B.ID_COND
     order by (CASE WHEN P.st_PAYMENT='ES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC, TS_INSMNT DESC
     fetch first 1 rows only)

How can I change it in order to do the porting without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing the inner query with:

```
(
    select st_PAYMENT FROM 
    (
        select st_PAYMENT from QLT.paymnts P
        where P.ID_COND=B.ID_COND
        order by (CASE WHEN P.st_PAYMENT='ES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC, TS_INSMNT DESC
    )
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
)
```